# Upper bound for the approximation of Lebesgue integral

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

Let $u:[-T/2,T/2]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a nonnegative measurable function $u(t)\ge0$. For each integer $n \ge 1$, define the $n$th order  approximation to the Lebesgue integral as follows: $$I_n=\sum_{m}m2^{-n}\mu_{m,n} \ \ \ \ \text{where}\ \  \mu_{m,n}=\mu(t:m2^{-n}\le u(t)\lt (m+1)2^{-n})$$Assume that $I_1$ is finite. I want to show that the change in going from the approximation of order $n$ to $n+1$ is nonnegative and upper bounded by $T2^{−n−1}$. According to the [MIT lecture notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-450-principles-of-digital-communications-i-fall-2006/resources/book_4/), this fact is obvious from the figure:[image]
I don't see how the figure shows that $I_{n+1} - I_{n}\le T2^{−n−1}$. Also I don't know how to prove it mathematically. We should have: $$I_{n+1} - I_{n} = \sum_{m}m(2^{-(n+1)}\mu_{m,n+1} - 2^{-n}\mu_{m,n}) = \sum_{m}m2^{-n}(2^{-1}\mu_{m,n+1}-\mu_{m,n})\le T2^{−n−1} \implies \sum_{m}m(2^{-1}\mu_{m,n+1}-\mu_{m,n})\le T2^{−1}$$ So we need to find a relation between $\mu_{m,n+1}$ and $\mu_{m,n}$ in general.

Comment: The idea is that the the difference $I_{n+1}-I_n$ is accounted by the sum  of the areas of rectangles (the horizontal crosshatched ones), with disjoint bases and height $2^{-n-1}$. Since the bases are disjoint and all contained in $[T/2,T/2]$, adding the areas gives something less than or equal to $T2^{-n-1}$. In symbols you want to write $\mu_{m,n}=\mu_{2m,n+1}+\mu_{2m+1,n+1}$ so that $I_{n+1}-I_n=\sum_m 2^{-n-1}\mu_{2m+1,n+1}\leq T2^{-n-1}$.

Comment: @Jose27 Thanks for the comment. How can we prove that $\mu_{m,n}=\mu_{2m,n+1}+\mu_{2m+1,n+1}$?

Comment: Write out the definitions of these quantities, for instance $m2^{-n}\leq u<(m+1)2^{-n}$ is equivalent to $2m2^{-n-1}\leq u<2(m+1)2^{-n-1}$.

Comment: @Jose27 Yes, so we need that $\mu(t:u(t)\in A \cup B) = \mu(t:u(t)\in A) + \mu(t: u(t)\in B) $ where $A$ and $B$ are disjoint intervals. Does this come from the properties of Lebesgue measure? I know that $\mu(A \cup B) = \mu(A) + \mu(B)$ but I'm not sure that these are equivalent.

Comment: @Jose27 I think I've found the answer. In fact, we are using the preimage here and it can be easily proved that $u^{-1}(A \cup B) = u^{-1}(A) \cup u^{-1}(B)$ and also $u^{-1}(A \cap B) = u^{-1}(A) \cap u^{-1}(B)$. Using these identities, the desired conclusion is reached. If you post your comment as an answer, I could accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea to prove this formally is to write
$$
\mu_{m,n}=\mu_{2m,n+1}+\mu_{2m+1,n+1},
$$
which follows from the fact that
$$
m2^{-n}\leq u(t)<(m+1)2^{-n} \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad 2m2^{-n-1}\leq u(t)<2(m+1)2^{-n-1}.
$$
This gives
$$
I_n= \sum_m m2^{-n} \mu_{m,n}= \sum_m [m2^{-n}\mu_{2m,n+1} +m2^{-n}\mu_{2m+1,n+1}]\\
= \sum_m [2m2^{-n-1}\mu_{2m,n+1} + (2m+1)2^{-n-1}\mu_{2m+1,n+1}] - \sum_m 2^{-n-1}\mu_{2m+1,n+1}\\
= I_{n+1}- \sum_m2^{-n-1}\mu_{2m+1,n+1}.
$$
Finally, we just note that, owing to countably additivity of Lebesgue measure,
$$
\sum_m 2^{-n-1} \mu_{2m+1,n+1} \leq T2^{-n-1}.
$$